# What does the module keyword mean in typescript?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, systemjs

I'm trying to figure some things related to ES6 modules. How to use namespaces together with angular and typescript.

Assume the following code represents an angular directive. Does anyone know what the `module` keyword mean and how can you access MyClass in other file.

```
// file1.ts
module NSpace.Space {
   export class MyClass {
      constructor() { ... }
      ...
   }
}
```

I have tried accessing on another file using and re-exporting, however

```
// file2.ts
import {MyClass} from 'file1';

export {MyClass}
```

I get this error: ***error TS2306: File 'file.ts' is not a module***

My questions are:

- why do I get this?
- what is this `module` keyword?
- do we create ES6 modules only based on the directory structure or can
  we actually use this notation? `module Space.Space1.Space2 ...`

From what I've read and experienced so far it seems that ES6 modules are defined based on file structure, that's why I get this error.

I have not written this code, that's why I'm asking. Also it might be useful to mention that I'm using System.JS for importing.

Comment: The `module` keyword is [specific to Typescript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#modules). It's not an ES6 feature, which assumes that all files loaded with `import` are modules by default

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `module` keyword in TypeScript caused a bit of confusion, so it is going to be renamed `namespace`.

Rather than use namespaces, though, you can organise your code by files / file system (which means the actual file location will match the perceived namespace. This is how "exteral modules" (TypeScript) work - and also how ECMAScript 2015 modules work.

So with a quick adjustment, you'll have:

```
// file1.ts
export class MyClass {
   constructor() { ... }
   ...
}
```

And then this will work:

```
import {MyClass} from 'file1';
```

If you compile targeting ES6, you'll notice that this line of code needs no translation, it matches the standard for module imports. If you target ES5 or lower, TypeScript will transform this statement for you (you can choose the transformation using the `--module` flag.

I tend to use the UMD compilation option, which means the output will work in web browsers (with RequireJS) or on Node. System JS is actually gaining a lot of traction currently, so you may want to consider that too. Eventually, browsers will simply natively support module loading.

Comment: That's exactly what I have understood about module loading. Actually it didn't make sense to use both ways for module definition.

Comment: Typo? "needs to translation" probably should be "needs no translation"

Comment: As of TypeScript 3.5.3 (August 2019) the `module` keyword still exists, but it outputs exactly the same output as `namespace`. `declare module "name"` however, is different and is used to declare type definitions for npm modules.